# Permissions for glance user in Ceph

Tags: openstack, ceph, openstack-glance

I use ceph as glance backend but very often i'm not able to delete an image. In my logs I have this error :

`PermissionError: error unprotecting snapshot`

So I tried to change user's permissions from:

`ceph auth caps client.glance mon 'allow r' osd 'allow class-read object_prefix rdb_children, allow rwx pool=glance-images'`

to

`ceph auth caps client.glance mon 'allow r' osd 'allow *'`

Now it works, but I would like to set something less open.

Do you know how to set it?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, it should be `rbd_children` not `rdb_children`. `rbd` is stands for "rados block device". The command will look like below:

```
ceph auth caps client.glance mon 'allow r' osd 'allow class-read object_prefix rbd_children, allow rwx pool=glance-images'
```

Answer (score 1):

The following fixed for me. Basically glance ceph user need read access on cinder volumes pool.

```
ceph auth caps client.glance mon 'allow r' osd 'allow class-read object_prefix rbd_children, allow rwx pool=glance-imagesm rx pool=volumes'
```